# Password verify with html. Get request reloads page instead of going to a submission page

Tags: javascript, html

I have an account registration form with html. I have a simple password verification check with minimal javascript. The verify fields are working correctly. If the passwords do not match a message is displayed when trying to hit the submit button. If they do match, when the submit is clicked it reload the same page instead of using a GET request to go to the results.html page. I am not sure why this is happening.

```
<form>
<fieldset>
<legend>Create Account:</legend>
Username: <input type="text"><br>
<p>Password:</p>
<input name="password" required="required" type="password" id="password" />
<p>Confirm Password:</p>
<input name="password_confirm" required="required" type="password" 
id="password_confirm" oninput="check(this)" />
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
function check(input) {
    if (input.value != document.getElementById('password').value) {
        input.setCustomValidity('Password Must be Matching.');
    } else {
        // input is valid -- reset the error message
        input.setCustomValidity('');
    }
}
</script>
<br /><br />
<form action="/path/to/results.html" method="get">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" 
     name="Submit" id="frm1_submit" />
</form>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you aware if you do `method="get"` then the password is going to be passed as part of the URL and _in clear text?_ Also, you can't put a `<form>` within another `<form>` - just move the _action_ and _method_ to the first one (Use your browser's DOM inspector and you'll see it has actually dropped the inner form)

Comment: I am aware of this. Thanks for pointing out the nested <form> problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the browser's default action on form submit events is to reload the page.

You need to call `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the page from refreshing.

```
document
  .querySelector('form')
  .addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
  })
```

## Update

So, after digging in a bit further, the reason that you were getting a page refresh instead of your expected form action (`<form action="/path/to/results.html" method="get">`) is because you have nested `<form>` elements.  The second form element is where you have defined your action, which is ignored by the browser.  Hence, the browser uses the default action, which is to refresh the page.  Cleaning up your HTML (in an opinionated way), it works as you would have expected.

```js
document
  .querySelector('[name="confirm"]')
  .addEventListener('input', check)

function check() {
  var password = document.querySelector('[name="password"]')
  var confirm = document.querySelector('[name="confirm"]')
  if (
    password.value !== confirm.value) {
      confirm.setCustomValidity('Password Must be Matching.');
  } else {
    confirm.setCustomValidity('');
  }
}
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<form action="results.html" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Create Account:</legend>
    <label>
      Username:
      <input type="text">
    </label>

    <label>
      Password:
      <input type="password" name="password" required>
    </label>

    <label>
      Confirm Password:
      <input type="password" name="confirm" required>
    </label>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Note: This is using the `POST` method, instead of `GET`. `GET` displays the input values in the URL, which is not good for sensitive information like passwords. `POST` includes the input values in the HTTP request instead.

Cheers

Comment: Should this be added into the js function?

Comment: Thank you for the concise answer. It now seems this renders the password validation ineffective, though.

Comment: I placed the js in a script tag in the html body, and it seems it is still not validating the passwords against each other. It is redirecting without checking.

Comment: @dj2 please focus only on the example I shared in the update

Comment: I'm wondering If I have an unclosed <form> somewhere else in my html doc. I put the first block above into a script tag, right above the form action block.

Comment: @DJ2 .... oh, maybe it's because I changed the HTML and removed the ID's you had earlier.  In my JS example, I'm selecting those elements differently than you were selecting them originally.  It's worth a double check.

Comment: After cleaning up my tags and such, +1 for that validation tool btw, it seems to be working now. I had misplaced tags in <head> that were causing problems, and also where I had placed my js script seemed to be raising an issue. Thanks again for the pointers.

Comment: @DJ2 Awesome!  Keep asking questions - we're all happy to help!  Feel free to tag me on your new questions. Cheers.